# Angular 2 ng-bootstrap ngbAlert error

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I had a self closing ng-bootstrap alert implemented as

```
<span *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
    <template ngbAlert [dismissOnTimeout]="5000" [type]="alert.type"><span [innerHTML]="alert.message"></span></template>
</span>
```

And it was working great. However, when I started a new project and copied this component as it is, it gives now

```
    Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dismissOnTimeout' since it isn't a known property of 'template'.
```

Here is my ts file if needed

```
import { Input, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-alert-closeable',
  templateUrl: './client/app/html/components/alert-closeable.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client/app/css/components/alert-closeable.css']
})
export class NgbdAlertCloseable {

  @Input()
  public alerts: Array<IAlert> = [];

  public addSuccess(msg: string, alert: IAlert) {
    this.alerts.push({
      type: 'success',
      message: msg
    });
  }

  public addInfo(msg: string, alert: IAlert) {
    this.alerts.push({
      type: 'info',
      message: msg
    });
  }

  public addWarning(msg: string, alert: IAlert) {
    this.alerts.push({
      type: 'warning',
      message: msg
    });
  }

  public addDanger(msg: string, alert: IAlert) {
    this.alerts.push({
      type: 'danger',
      message: msg
    });
  }

}

interface IAlert {
  type: string;
  message: string;
}
```

What should be the problem here? It was working great previously.

Comment: Which exactly package of ng2 bootstrap do you use? `ng-bootstrap` or `ng2-bootstrap`? If you use ng2-bootstrap then it should be `<alert [dismissOnTimeout]=...`  https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/master/components/alert/alert.component.ts on other hand if you use ng-bootstrap then it should be `<ngb-alert ..` and there is no `dismissOnTimeout` property on alert https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/alert/alert.ts

Comment: I am using both of them on different components, but I can't remember which of them I was using for alerts. Why was it working before if my usage is wrong?

Comment: Because it was in 1.0.0-alpha.5 https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/1.0.0-alpha.5/src/alert/alert.ts#L62

Comment: Per changelog https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1 And here is demo https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/demo/src/app/components/alert/demos/selfclosing/alert-selfclosing.ts